# System.Linq.Dynamic - Select Column Value Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am getting an issue in `Select`. Following is the Code :-

```
    string para = "DynamicValue";
    var paraData = ctx.tblEmployee.Where("id=1").Select("new(" + para + ")");
    string value = para + "_" + paraData;
```

In `paraData`, I dont get the value, instead i get a long query expression.

How to get the Value of the Selected Column in the Table?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would solve it , you should not use strings in Where och Select methods where an expression is expected

```
string para = "DynamicValue";
var paraData = ctx.tblEmployee.Where(x => x.id==1).Select(x =>  x.para );
string value = para + "_" + paraData;
```

Comment: not sure havnt compiled it,it was written to point out that Where and Select methods do not take string as a parameter and for sure it answers the question